# How to implement a callback in Javascript onload event

Tags: javascript, callback, onload, dom-events

I really don't understand... I'm a beginner in Javascript.

I have attached my function `onLoadDocument` to the `document.onload` event.

The callback function absolutely have to be executed after `function111()` and `function222()` have totally finished their job.

Actually, the callback is executed too soon and it causes a problem to `function111` and `function222`.

How to execute the callback function ONLY when `function111` and `function222` will have finished their job?

```
function onLoadDocument(event, callback) {
    function111();
    function222();
    callback();
}

function after() {
    firstOpeningWindow = false;
}

document.onload = onLoadDocument(event, after);
```

Comment: `window.onload = function (event) {onLoadDocument(event, after);}`. `document` doesn't have `onload` event.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that a callback is a function reference, but this line:

```
onLoadDocument(event, after)
```

is a function invocation and therefore runs immediately. Also, it's `window` that has a `load` event, not `document`.

```
function onLoadDocument(callback) {
    function111();
    function222();
    callback();
}

function after() {
    firstOpeningWindow = false;
}

// You have to supply a function reference here. So, to pass arguments
// you'd need to wrap your function invocation in another function that
// will be the callback
window.onload = function() { onLoadDocument(after) };
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `window.onload` (as a commenter on another answer said,, `document.onload` doesn't exist) takes a function, which is executed when the event happens. You're not passing in a function here, you're passing in the *return value* of `onLoadDocument(event, after)`. This is `undefined` - and to get that, the browser is executing the function, which is too early for you.

The solution is just to have `onLoadDocument` return a function:

```
function onLoadDocument(event, callback) {
    return function () {
        function111();
        function222();
        callback();
    }
}

function after() {
    firstOpeningWindow = false;
}

window.onload = onLoadDocument(event, after);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function is called when you call the function, so:

```
document.onload = onLoadDocument(event, after);
```

… calls `onLoadDocument` **immediately** and assigns the return value to `onload` (which is pointless because the return value is not a function).

If you want to take this approach, then you need to write a factory which generates your onload function using a closure:

```
function onLoadDocumentFactory(callback) {
    function onLoadDocument(event) {
        function111();
        function222();
        callback();
    }
    return onLoadDocument;
}

function after() {
  firstOpeningWindow = false;
}

document.onload = onLoadDocument(after);
```

That said, it would be easier just to add your functions in order using the modern `addEventListener`.

```js
function function111() {
  console.log(111);
}

function function222() {
  console.log(222);
}

function after() {
  console.log("after");
}

addEventListener("load", function111);
addEventListener("load", function222);
addEventListener("load", after);
```

Comment: `document` doesn't have `onload` event.