# How to get the number of pages of a pdf file

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following javascript solution to get the number of pages of a file :

```
const reader = new FileReader()
reader.readAsBinaryString(file)
reader.onloadend = function () {
 const count = reader.result.match(/\/Type[\s]*\/Page[^s]/g).length
 console.log('Number of Pages:', count)
}
```

The number of pages is correct in the console but I don't know how to extract that number from the scope of the reader so I can use it elsewhere.

Comment: `reader.onloadend` is likely asynchronous. So you will need to follow an async style to access the variable.

Comment: the suggested similar question is a bit confusing for me, I understand that I have to found a way to wait for the result but I don't understand how to do it

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer. Look at step 2 specifically.

Comment: Honestly this is beyond my capabilities for now, I kind of understand the solution they wrote but I failed to see how to use it in my case.

Comment: `request.onload` in the answer is almost identical to `reader.onloadend`?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, is it in the accepted answer? When you say step 2, are you referring to the callback solution?

Comment: Yes that is the solution I was referring to. Since `onloadend` is a callback, it's a solution that seems to fit the best.

Comment: So should i do something like ```reader.onloadend = function callback () { ... return count }``` ?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54951205/how-to-implement-a-callback-in-javascript-onload-event even though it talks about `window.onload` the approach is similar to what you need.

Comment: I've tried to write the code but couldn't make it work, I thought I understand how it works but nop